# unexpected outcome caused by scipy.csr_matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.sparse import *
>>> x1 = np.eye(3, dtype=float)
>>> x2 = csr_matrix(x1, dtype=float, shape =x1.shape)
>>> assert x2.todense().any()==x1.any()  ## holds true
>>> w = np.ones((3,1))
>>> dw1 = w - x1[:,0]
>>> dw2 = w - x2[:,0]
```

which gives me

```
>>> print dw1
[[ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]]
```

while

```
>>> print dw2
[[ 0.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

My question is why dw1 and dw2 differ? Should they defer, Is it a bug? Many Thanks!

Comment: `x2` is a sparse *matrix*, and behaves much like a dense matrix, e.g. `np.matrix(x1)`.  Here `x2[:,0]` is (3,1) matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slicing/indexing issue. The questionable line here is

```
w - x1[:, 0]
```

which has nothing to do with sparseness. You have sliced x1, obtaining a 1D array. When this gets subtracted from w, numpy broadcasts this array back into a 3 by 3 matrix (because it equates the number of columns of both terms), which I guess is not what you wanted.

It looks like you just wanted the **submatrix** consisting of the first column of x1. This would be

```
w - x1[:, [0]]
```

returning

```
array([[ 0.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

consistent with the other result.

In case of a sparse matrix, you automatically get a submatrix (not a 1D array) because indexing works differently for those.

Answer (score 2):

It's because those slices are `1D` and `2D` respectively -

```
In [23]: x1[:,0]
Out[23]: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.])

In [24]: x2[:,0].toarray()
Out[24]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])

In [29]: x1[:,0].ndim
Out[29]: 1

In [30]: x2[:,0].toarray().ndim
Out[30]: 2
```

Also, `w` is a 2D array -

```
In [33]: w
Out[33]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])

In [34]: w.ndim
Out[34]: 2
```

So, with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the subtractions from `w` are performed along different axes of `w` namely second and first axis respectively.